# Calling a variable from the data retrieved in a textfile

Tags: vb.net, text-files, filestream, streamreader

I want to reference the values of variables that I have declared in my code from inside my text file.  I want the variables referenced in the text file to be replaced by their appropriate values, depending on what the variables in the code currently equal, but I am having problems with it.

The contents of my text file, `post.txt` is:

> I am gonna display" & first & "and" & second & "text

Here is my code:

```
Dim Test As String
Dim first As String = "first word"
Dim second As String = "second word"

Dim pStream As New System.IO.FileStream("post.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim pReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(pStream)

Test = pReader.ReadLine()

pStream.Close()
pReader.Close()

SampleTextbox.Text = Test
```

I want my `SampleTextbox` to display the following:

> I am gonna display first word and second word text

But, instead, it still displays exactly what is being retrieved from the text file, which is:

> I am gonna display" & first & "and" & second & "text

I have never tried calling variables from a text file, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is "no".  Variables do not work like that.  Variables are simply a way in your code to conveniently refer to the memory locations where data is stored.  When your source code is built into an assembly, your original source code no longer even exists, as part of that resulting assembly.

You should not think of text files as being an extension of your source code.  Text files are simply a way to store raw data to disk.  The data doesn't "run".  The data doesn't do anything, in and of itself.  The data has no "access" to your source code.  Your program must do all the work if you want it to do something with or to the data.

So, if you want to do something like that, you'll need to parse and manipulate the data via code that you write.  How easy or difficult it is to perform a task like this depends entirely on how difficult your file format is to parse and work with.  The format you have chosen is rather difficult, which is why someone else suggested RegEx.  RegEx gives you a lot of power to parse complicated data.  However, if you have control over the format of your data, it would be a far better approach to simply change your file format to something that is easier to work with.  You could use a standard format like XML.  With XML, you could choose to format the data in any number of different ways, depending on your needs.  For instance, you could format it like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
I am gonna display <first/> and <second/> text.
</document>
```

Or this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
I am gonna display <var name="first"/> and <var name="second"/> text.
</document>
```

Or this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
I am gonna display <var>first</var> and <var>second</var> text.
</document>
```

Then, you could use any of the XML tools in the .NET framework to load the XML document and replace the variable elements with the proper values.  In fact, you could even use XSLT, which would be cool, but I digress.

I suspect, however, that for your needs, changing your format to use simple placeholders, like the following, would probably make more sense:

> I am gonna display %FIRST% and %SECOND% text.

Then, you could simply replace the placeholders in the string with their variable values, like this:

```vb
Dim first As String = "first word"
Dim second As String = "second word"
Dim data As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("post.txt")
data = data.Replace("%FIRST%", first)
data = data.Replace("%SECOND%", second)
SampleTextbox.Text = data
```

Comment: Thanks alot man it helped me big time. i can now sleep well. this has been bothering me for days already. you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described is to use Regex. For further information check the link below:

[Visual Basic (2010) - Using variables in embedded text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336897/visual-basic-2010-using-variables-in-embedded-text-files)